# How can place 2 divs in the same row,if the second div has display:flex property?

Tags: html, css

I am making a navbar in which
I want to place 2 divs in the same row, however the second div has `display:flex` property, in order for this to work, both divs need to have `display:inline-block`

Do I need to abandon flexbox if i want both divs in the same row?, Cause I really want to use `justify-content:space-between` in my navbar

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.top-banner {
  background-color: #632D1D;
  height: 50px;
}

.logo {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.navigation {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.nav-links {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-banner"></div>
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="logo">SaleByFarmer</div>
  <div class="nav-links">
    <a href="#mangoes">Mangoes</a>
    <a href="#fruits">Fruits</a>
    <a href="#flowers">Flowers</a>
    <a href="#ourstory">Our Story</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
  <i src="/icons/cart-shopping-solid.svg" class="shopping-cart-icon">
    </div>
```

[image]

This is what my site looks like currently

Comment: If I'm understanding it right, you could try using `display: flex` on the `.navigation` div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that

```css
.navigation{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

is the key in this case

```css
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.top-banner{
    background-color: #632D1D;
    height:50px;
}

.logo{
    display:inline;
    margin-left:10%;
}



.navigation{
    margin:0 auto;
    height:80px;
    background-color: bisque;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    
}


.nav-links {
    background-color: aqua;
    width:50%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin:0 auto;

  }
```

```html
    <div class="top-banner"></div>

    <div class="navigation">

        <div class="logo">SaleByFarmer</div>

        <div class="nav-links">
            <a href="#mangoes">Mangoes</a>
            <a href="#fruits">Fruits</a>
            <a href="#flowers">Flowers</a>
            <a href="#ourstory">Our Story</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
        </div>

        <i src="/icons/cart-shopping-solid.svg" class="shopping-cart-icon"></i>





    </div>
```